# flexbox height sub childs class

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two identical cards with a defined height.

The first card (example #1) when it doesn't have enough content, behaves as I want (pushes the footer down), no problem here.

I have a problem with the second card:
When there is a lot of content I must scroll, but this scroll should not be controlled by the main ".content" element, it must be the ".contentExt" class that decides this functionality.

If you add the line to

```
.card .content {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 car;
    overflow: auto; /* This line*/
  }
```

This line does what is required, but it is not the right place, I have to do it in ".contentExt".

You can think of something like inheriting height from parent to child. or something like cards within cards, but for each one its maximum height will be that of the previous parent.

I've searched a lot of information and I can't find the solution.

[Code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/expansiondiego/z61thr9u/3/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to `.card`, elements must have a defined height for horizontal scroll to work

**Edit: to add overflow to`.contentExt`**

Just add `height: 100%;` to `.card .content`

Comment: As I said before, the idea is to add classes to .contentExt, if I do it as you say it will work, but it is not the case.